# Can MessageBox pause exception handling in a win32 window procedure?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I used a try-catch clause for exception handling of my window procedure to simply report the error using a message box and post a `WM_CLOSE` message. I write the following simple implementation to reproduce the problem.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
try { 
    switch (message) 
    { 
        case WM_CREATE: {         
            SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER_MOVE, 1500, (TIMERPROC)NULL); 
        }break; 
        case WM_TIMER: { 
        //---------------Here throws the exception 
            throw std::string("time up"); 
        //----------------------------------------       
        }break; 
        case WM_DESTROY: { 
            KillTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER_MOVE); 
            PostQuitMessage(0);             
        }break; 
        default: 
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); 
        } 
        return 0; 
} 
catch (const std::string& e) { 
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Exception has been thrown."), TEXT("Emmmm"), MB_SYSTEMMODAL); 
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

I thought that once a `WM_TIMER` gets dispatched, the execution will shortly branch into the catch clause and wait for the `MessageBox` to return **without doing anything else**. But it turns out that this is not the case. The program doesn't seem to wait the return of `MessageBox`, instead, it still receives a `WM_TIMER` and generates a message box every 1.5 second. As a result, many message boxes show up, and the only way to terminate the whole program is to close the latest generated message box instead of any other earlier generated ones.

So, is it a bad practice to report error from window procedure using message box?

Comment: According to the documentation of [`WM_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer), an application should return `0` if it processes the message. You are violating this rule by not returning anything. I am not sure what consequences this could have.

Comment: MessageBox, like any dialog, pumps a message loop (GetMessage+DispatchMessage) so it can paint itself and respond to user input.  That message loop dispatches your messages as well.  You'll have to disable the timer.

Comment: Call `KillTimer` before throwing the exception.  Also, I wouldn't throw an exception at all here.  Just call `MessageBox` after calling `KillTimer` and then post your `WM_CLOSE` message

Comment: @HansPassant I think you are right. Shortly after posted this question (actually I posted it eight hours ago, because staging ground consumed some time),  I reconsidered the bizarre behavior of my program during debugging with break points, and gradually arrived at a conclusion same as yours. The only difference was that I was not sure whether this is the case.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks for your advice. I'm going to modify my code as you said.

Comment: It should also be sufficient to call `KillTimer` in the exception handler, before calling `MessageBox`.